# how to create exe file from my class and file on runtime

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make exe file with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464613/how-to-make-exe-file-with-c-sharp)

i have one program in c#. this program get parameters(file for example *.jpg) from user and finally after click user on build button my program create one other program in windows application (cs:Form) that is has one viewer for images and store app in one exe file. i need help for how to create exe file from form class.

Comment: You already asked this 10 minutes ago and it has been answered! Why again?!

Comment: Yea and the same person answered the question...sigh

Comment: That is not my point, the question has been closed as not a real question. So he copies the content of that question without changing anything and opens a new one. -1

Comment: The way I interpret this question is that he has built a Windows Form which accepts input of a path to an image file, and it has a button on it. When he clicks the button, he wants to compile an .exe file with the specified path on the spot to display the image in a new process. If I have interpreted correctly, this is completely the wrong way to go about this task.

Comment: @niemiro In the context of his original question, I don't think your interpretation is correct.  I believe he is trying to somewhat describe his application and is telling us that he wants to send it to an executable.  That said, that is just my interpretation as well

Comment: @DavidL Thank you very much for your comment. In many ways it seems more likely, and I welcome your input. You are problem more correct, in retrospect, but, TBH, I don't think anyone really knows for sure :p. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I just answered this for you on your closed question.

This is a great tutorial on building an EXE from your code using VS2010 express

If you end up working through the tutorial and then get stuck, then post here and we can help you.  Right now we don't know with what or where you are stuck.

Per Gabe's request, from another source. http://www.ehow.com/how_6352221_create-studio-2008-express-edition.html

Instructions

1

Open your application in Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition.

2
Click Build. You have two choices now: You can choose to simply build an EXE file and its libraries or you can choose to publish a setup application that will install the program on a client's computer. This will automatically build "Start" menu shortcuts and an uninstallation program for your application.

If you just want to build an EXE file, go to step three. If you want to publish a setup program, go to step four.

3

Click "build (your project name)."

If there are no errors in your project, then the status bar at the bottom of the window will soon read "Build succeeded."

Navigate to the location of your project using Windows Explorer. By default, it will be in the folder "My Documents" under Windows XP.

To get there, click "Start," "My Documents," "Visual Studio 2008," "Projects," and then the folder with the name of your project. Again, there will be another folder with the same name as your project.

Go into the "bin" directory. There will be either a "Debug" folder or a "Release" folder here (or both.) Choose "Release" if you have it.

Your .EXE file will be in that folder.

4

Click "Publish (your project name)."

Click "Browse" and select the location where you wish to publish your application. For the moment, a folder on the desktop would be a good choice.

In the next window, you'll be asked how the users will install the application. Choose "from an executable file."

Next, you'll be asked how the application should check for updates to itself. For the moment, choose "This application will not check for updates."

Click "Finish."

Three files will be placed in the folder on your Desktop: the setup application, an autorun.ini file to allow your setup program to be autorun from a CD and a manifest file that is needed by the setup application.

Read more: How to Create EXE Program Files in Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition | eHow.com http://www.ehow.com/how_6352221_create-studio-2008-express-edition.html#ixzz2IjDfQpUQ

Comment: @NabiKarampoor Seems like you gave the answer it's fair 2 minutes and 30 seconds of effort...

Comment: @NabiKarampoor Which exact step do you not understand?